# iAd doesn't shows correct

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

i'm developing dict for iOS, and try to use iAd for monetization. I done step by step with examples, except creating ad view, but ad doesn't show correct.

[image: start screen]

[image: ad loaded]

[image: view controller]

my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, -50); //don't work
    adView.delegate=self;
    self.bannerIsVisible=NO;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    if (!self.bannerIsVisible){
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 50); //works well
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    if (self.bannerIsVisible){
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}
```

I work with storyboard, using autolayout, tried to set

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

Is it showing in the wrong position, or just not showing the ad when built in release mode? If it is in the wrong position, don't use the autoresizingMask and use the autolayout constraints in the storyboard instead. If it is not showing up after building in release/submitting to app store, then you most likely still need to register for the iAd network through iTunesConnect.

It looks like you are using iOS 7. There is a really easy way to add iAds if you don't mind it showing up on the bottom of the view:

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

yourViewController.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
```

You do not need to implement any other show/hide methods if you use this property. Apple's WWDC 2013 video titled "iAd Integration and Best Practices" explains this in detail:

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. I solved this problem with enable adView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES;